# Using percentage change with different sample sizes, which is more significant?

Tags: percentage

I have some data that is looking at Virtual vs. Face to Face appointments (at a hospital) - please see data in pic below. This is split by first appointments and follow up appointments. I am comparing one month of data to another month (peak month vs. latest month). As expected, the number of face to face appointments is increasing whilst the number of virtual appointments is decreasing (as lockdown measures are relaxed). For virtual appointments, how do I work out if it is first or follow up appointments where the virtual appointments are most impacted? For example it is suspected that as lockdown measures ease, clinicians are returning to 'business as usual' for first appointments, seeing more patients face to face, whereas it's suspected that follow up appointments will not be impacted as much and will remain more virtual. The second picture is the data for another hospital, how do I work out which of these 2 hospitals has seen a greater reduction in virtual appointments? I am confused because I don't know how the percentage increase for face to face appointments impacts the percentage decrease of virtual appointments. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Specifically wrt whether the information is for *first or follow up appointments*, this doesn't seem like something that is estimable. Wouldn't this require a flag in the physical data indicating which type of appointment has been made?

Comment: In my opinion, you need the State reported daily COVID-19 cases data. Use the latter to account for the change in F2F appointments (as hospitalization rate increases for COVID-19, F2F drops, and Virtual rises, while declines in COVID-19 cases, encourages and frees-up F2F).  Also, movements in total appointments likely follows some lagged function of COVID-19 cases. The ratio of F2F/Virtual also may shift with the COVID.  You cannot leave the COVID variable out of the analysis and have it make sense in my estimation. Note, you are already looking at peaks (COVID related) in your analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, to clarify (I didn't make this clear in my original post) these appointments are for a cardiology clinic in the UK and the peak month is the month where the % of virtual appointments was at it's highest. The total number of appointments has not changed much, for the first hospital there were 694 appointments in the peak month and 601 appointments in the latest month, but the number of face to face appointments are increasing and the virtual decreasing. In reply to the first comment, the data is split by first and follow up appointments already.

Comment: I am looking at certain specialties where there has been a steep decline in the number of virtual appointments and then I am looking at all of the hospitals in a certain area and trying to pinpoint which of the hospitals have seen the steepest decline